How escape an = when getting a value from Azure Key Vault for Azure Functions
I have an Azure Function with an environment variable set to obtain the value from a key vault:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=<vaultName>;SecretName=<secretName>)

We are getting issues when the value in the key vault has an "=" in the secret, e.g.
thisisaverygoodsecret=

If we store the secret against the environment variable directly, the application works as expected. I assume we need to escape the = in some way, but I can't see anything in the Microsoft docs.
We have several other Function variables obtained in the same way, so there is no problem with the link to the Key Vault.

The way you've laid this out should be fine. Connection strings will pretty much always fall into this bucket, so it's a fairly common use case.
There is some missing information here that would help - when you debug the function, are you able to see what the value of the secret is once it's loaded into the FA? If it's splitting/truncating the value, that would potentially be a different issue than if it's not getting the value back at all. For instance, it's possible that access between the KV & FA is not configured correctly and the FA isn't able to access or unwrap the value.

How are you fetching the secret value in your code? I am able to get the value just by using simple code when the secret has = in it. @RichardPayne

I published a debug build, attached VS and tested adding the value directly and with Key Vault. Magically, both are the same and the link to the KV is now working as expected.

I have added @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=<vaultName>;SecretName=<secretName>) in App Settings which has = in its value.
I have used Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("secretValue"); to fetch the secret value from key vault and got the expected response.
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string secretValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("secretValue");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. The secret value is: {secretValue}";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}


